# Adding values to existing (Hash)key, without over-writing the existing value(s)?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Simplified version:

```
ar=['name: Joe', 'name: Jack', 'name: Jill']

hash={}

ar.each{|line| if line.include?('name'); hash['name'] = line;end;}

puts hash
```

My aim is to add all the elements in the array to the 'name'-key, but my code seeme to over-write the existing value.

Is'nt it possible to have multiple values assigned to one single key? I'd rather not use an array as value.

### Edit:

I realized that my first example did'nt cover the whole problem:

extend the array to:
    ar=['name: Joe', 'name: Jack', 'name: Jill', age: 29', 'age: 32', 'misc: Great weather']

What i'd is to have the 'name's grouped under the key 'name', and so on.

The number of attributes/keys is not known beforehand, so the arrays will have top be made dynamiclly.

Comment: What result are you expecting when you call `hash[name]`?  Are you expecting to get back a particular name, or are you expecting back all of the names that have been added?

Comment: I was kind of hoping for all of them, as separate strings. But it seems that an array is the way to go.

Comment: To your edit, then you should create new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option besides using an array as a value. Otherwise how would you retrieve the multiple values? You'd need some kind of enumerable anyway, so there's no problem with using an array.

Try something like this:

```
hash = {}
ar = ['name: Joe', 'name: Jack', 'name: Jill']

hash['name'] = ar.select {|l| l.include? 'name'}.collect {|l| l.split.last}

hash # => {"name"=>["Joe", "Jack", "Jill"]}
```

Or, a little more simply:

```
hash = {"name" => ar.select {|l| l.include? 'name'}.collect {|l| l.split.last} }
```

---

For your edited question:

```
hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
ar.each {|l| k,v = l.split(": "); hash[k] << v }
hash # => {"name"=>["Joe", "Jack", "Jill"], "foo"=>["bar"]}
```

Comment: I thought there would be a way to store separate variables under one key, cant really explain why, but i seemed likely.. :s Thanks.

Comment: Think about what it means to store multiple things under one key, though... you'd still have to do something like `for name in hash["name"]`... which is exactly how this works :)

Comment: Sorry, but i could'nt figure out how to transfer your solution to my (now) extended problem.